# QGIS, Exporting .svg from a map, I can not produce it with as much resolution as in the main window

Tags: qgis, export, esri-geodatabase, mapping, resolution

I am doing a PhD in wildfire modelling so that I need to deal with GIS data, mostly for visualizing purposes and data preprocessing.

I am connecting to a XYZ tiles to produce a satellite map. In particular this connector

[https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D)

This is how I can visualize the map with some of the other layers on top of it

[image]

If I check the map layer, This is how I visualize it (I now this is a preview and it does not reflect the real export, or at least, this is the theory I have grasped from other similar posts)

[image]

I need to export the map as a .svg because I need the other layers as a vectorial image for appropiate journal submission requirements. If I export the map as .svg, I get this,

[image]

I think it clearly shows how on the main QGIS windows the resolution is better and how after exporting I can not manage to get the same resolution as a raster. I tried to change the dpi in the corresponding map properties windows but it only improves the resolution up to a certain point (about 192 dpi, which is the "high resolution" option stated in the new connection panel by the way).

I checked other answers but I could not get a positive solution. Also, these were old questions posted in this Stack (years ago). I hope this can be interesting to the community and maybe somebody can provide a solution to my case.

Comment: The SVG export show a warning stating some problem and suggest to export to PDF (Vector PDF can be generated) and then to convert the PDF to SVG, you could try that and see if it improve thing…

Comment: In which format is the green line? Can you share the green line data?

Comment: The green line is the end result of converting a raster to polygon type, then segmenting areas I did not want and finally extracting the "perimeter" of the polygon to derive a line. So that it is a polygonal feature. Thank you for your interest @GforGIS

Comment: @J.R I will try to do that, I did not start exporting the PDF because in later postprocessing using inkscape I got weird conversions with other polygonal data overlapping the map. Thank you I will check that conversion!